# FXML prefHeight and prefWidth vs height and width of scene

Tags: javafx, fxml

In my `fxml` file the root element looks like this:

```
<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.AbweichungenKonfigurationController">
   ...
</SplitPane>
```

And the class that invokes the fxml file looks like that:

Now, the size defined in the fxml file:

```
prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0"
```

is overwritten by the scene size:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 800));
```

The window that appears has the size defined in the constructor of the scene!

Is there any opportunity to use the size defined in the fxml file? Or how should I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `Scene` will force its root to take the size of the `Scene`, irrespective of its min/pref/max size.

Try wrapping your `SplitPane` in a `StackPane`, with no size constraints on the `StackPane`. The `StackPane` will respect the `SplitPane`'s preferred size:

```
<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.AbweichungenKonfigurationController">

    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" >
       ...
    </SplitPane>

</StackPane>
```